# Yii framework - Change module URL

Tags: php, url, yii

I have a module called 'admin' in my application, which is accessible at /mysite/admin. To improve the site security I want to change this URL to something more difficult to guess to the normal users and only the site admin will know.

I tried urlManager rules but couldn't get the desired result, for example:

```
'admin-panel'=>'admin/default/index', 
'admin-panel/login'=>'admin/default/login'
```

But this will only work for those two URLs.

So the only thing I can think of now is to rename the actual module. The module name is referenced a lot throughout the app so that it is too difficult to do. anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rules=>array(
    'admin-panel'                            =>'admin',
    'admin-panel/<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>/<id:\d+>' =>'admin/<_c>/<_a>/<id>',
    'admin-panel/<_c:\w+>/<_a:\w+>'          =>'admin/<_c>/<_a>',
    'admin-panel/<_c:\w+>'                   =>'admin/<_c>',
)
```

But it's just alias - your admin module still will be available by /admin/ URL. Actually you must check access for users, don't try to hide your admin panel.

Comment: yes. you are right. but i wonder if is there any way to hide,restrict the old path?

Comment: Well, you can parse a route and threw 403 CHttpException (Forbidden) if requested module's name is 'admin'. It will redirect user to /site/error and shows exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [URL Management (Parameterizing Routes)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#parameterizing-routes) from the Definitive Guide.
Something like this should do the job:

```
array(
  '<_c:(admin\-panel)>/<_a>' => 'admin/default/<_a>',
)
```

But you're just 'renaming' your default controller in the admin module and it will still be accessible under your old URL.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
'admin-panel'=>'admin',
'admin-panel/<controller:\w+>'=>'admin/<controller>',
'admin-panel/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'admin/<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: yes. it is working. but it is still be available in the old url too. is there any other way to restrict or redirect to the speicified path?

Comment: You can try setting a rule for "admin" that generates an error via Yii -- I'm not sure if that would cause problems, otherwise set up something via apache (put a rule in your .htaccess before the bootstrap rewrite) or rename the module.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            'module/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            'module/<m:\w+>/<c:\w+>/<a:\w+>'=>'<m>/<c>/<a>',
        )
    ),
```